# Comparing two variables from different database tables using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables in my database. The first one, "products", has two rows - "id" and "title" and has an image bound to it on the server. The second, "templates" has three rows - "id", "title" and "category" and also has an image bound to it. What I want is, when the "title" from "products" and the "category" from "templates" are the same, the images only belonging to the matching category appear. For example if the title is "wine" then only the pictures that are bound to the "wine" category should appear.

```
<!--PRODUCTS-->
<h4>Choose Product</h4>
<div id="products" class="row">
<?php
while ($one = $products->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
        <a class="thumbnail"  data-id="<?= $one['id'] ?>">
            <img src="/files/products/<?= $one['id'] ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $one['title'] ?>">
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>

<!--TEMPLATES-->

<h4>Choose Template</h4>
<div id="templates" class="row">
<?php
while ($one = $templates->fetch()) {
    ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" data-price="<?= $one['price'] ?>" data-id="<?= $one['id'] ?>">
                <img src="/files/templates/example/<?= $one['id'] ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $one['title'] ?>">
            </a>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

As it stands now, every picture in the templates/example file appears. Is there a way to do it without changing the code much? I don't know if the title of the question is correct, edit it to a more appropriate one if needed.

Comment: why don't you use Join??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done MySQL in a while but methinks the kind of query you're looking for is something like:

```
SELECT
    t.image
FROM
    templates AS t
JOIN
    products AS p
ON
    t.category = p.title
WHERE
    t.category = 'wine'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, where to add those lines? My "products" and "templates" are defined already in a file "home.php" like this: $products = $DB->query('SELECT * FROM products');
$templates = $DB->query('SELECT * FROM templates');

Comment: This is a query, so to use it in your case: `$imageQuery = $DB->query('SELECT t.image ... LIMIT 1');` SQL is in itself a complete language rather than just a random tool PHP uses to store stuff. You should look into furthering your knowledge on SQL on its own as it can be quite handy. Things like stored procedures and triggers can make development easier and more secure in the future.